# Akka: Custom akka supervision strategies not registered using Java

Tags: java, akka, actor, akka-supervision

I am going to explore `Akka` life cycle and `Akka` actors supervision strategies. I am creating my own exceptions and override `public SupervisorStrategy supervisorStrategy()` method for exploring the life-cycle of akka and their recovery strategies. Following is my code:

```
public class JavaActor extends AbstractActor {

@Override
public PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> receive() {
    System.out.println("----   In the receive method "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return ReceiveBuilder.
            matchEquals("Ping" , s -> {
                System.out.println("$$$ Ping Match Successfully");
                throw new EsclateException("Might be esclate");
            }).
            matchAny(x -> {
                System.out.println("### Matched value is :  "+ x);
                sender().tell(new Status.Failure(new Exception("unknown message")), self());
            }).build();
}

@Override
public void preRestart(Throwable reason, Option<Object> message) throws Exception {
    super.preRestart(reason, message);
    System.out.println(">>> Actor preRestart method calls : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

@Override
public void postRestart(Throwable reason) throws Exception {
    super.postRestart(reason);
    System.out.println(">>> Actor postRestart method calls : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

@Override
public void preStart() throws Exception {
    super.preStart();
    System.out.println(">>> Actor preStart method calls "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

@Override
public void postStop() throws Exception {
    super.postStop();
    System.out.println(">>> Actor postStop method calls "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

@Override
public SupervisorStrategy supervisorStrategy() {
    System.out.println("**** SupervisorStrategy Override Successfully ****");
    return new OneForOneStrategy(5, Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES),
            DeciderBuilder.match(ResumeException.class, e -> SupervisorStrategy.resume())
            .match(RestartException.class, e -> SupervisorStrategy.restart())
            .match(StopException.class, e -> SupervisorStrategy.stop())
            .match(EsclateException.class, e -> SupervisorStrategy.escalate())
            .matchAny(e -> SupervisorStrategy.escalate()).build());

}}
```

In the `receive()` method when I throw the `EsclateException` the logs continues and not terminate the actor. But when I replace the exception code with `throw new Error()`, the actors stop the work and terminate. As from output, it seems that, my `SupervisorStrategy`not registered and actors run on default `SupervisorStrategy`. How can I register my strategies?

Below is my calling code:

```
public class JavaActorTest {

public static ActorSystem system;

@BeforeClass
public static void start() {
    system = ActorSystem.create("ActorLifeCycleTest");
}

@AfterClass
public static void cleanup() {
    JavaTestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system);
    system = null;
}

@Test
public void testActorCreation(){
    TestActorRef<JavaActor> actorRef = TestActorRef.create(system, Props.create(JavaActor.class));
    actorRef.tell("Ping", ActorRef.noSender());
    assertThat(true, is(true));
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An actor is supervised by its parent not by itself, so the `supervisorStrategy` of its parent actor is what will be applied when an actor fails.

In your sample you do not include a parent of your own so the user guardian actor supervision is applied.

You can read more about supervision in the docs here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/general/supervision.html#supervision

Comment: Hey @johanandren is it possible for change guardian supervision strategy?

Comment: Yes, it is mentioned in the docs. But I recommend you to introduce your own supervisor actor instead of changing the user guardian strategy.

Comment: that's cool, can you please send the link, where they mention for change guardian strategy? i just want to explore more, that's whey trying to change guardian strategy.

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/general/supervision.html#_user__The_Guardian_Actor